# Photoshop - How to create a completely non anti-aliased image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, anti-aliasing, microsoft-paint

How to create a completely non anti-aliased image...

[image]

see the white dots on the body outline... by the way this thing is transparent and is being displayed on desktop via an application... anyways...

- 1 -  what i did was took a stock image of body...
- 2 - removed background
- 3 - selected the left area that is the body and painted it...
- 4 - then expanded the selection 1px and inverted the selection.. and painted the slection
- 5 - so the body outline was empty
- 6 - then i selected the empty area and painted it in a new layer
- 7 - got rid of the previous layer...

during 6 i am not getting solid painting... its antialiasing the filling or brush paint etc...

can any one tell me how to make it completely **non-anti-alias**

Comment: p.s. the image i am doing is very small... 120 px X 160 px .. 9999 px/com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Image-menu, Adjustments, Posterize with two levels (afterwards you may have to remove the 2nd of the two colors with the magic-wand selection tool (non-continous selection)).

Comment: the resulting image isn't so great because of staircase effect but yo did solved the "asked" problem...

Comment: Maybe you can improve the whole thing if you use the antialiased image with a bit of layer transparency and put it under the the non-antaliased version.

Or you could turn the antialiasing into transparency (roughly speaking something along the lines of this article, lighter pixels more opaque than dark ones: http://darkhorizons.emissionline.com/PSSelect.htm )

Answer (score 1):

You can get a lot of mileage out of shifting to indexed color (Image->Mode->Indexed Color) and then back to RGB. I copied the image from your question, converted to Indexed Color (Local/Adaptive, 2 colors, Forced Black & White) and ended up with a non-antialiased image. From there, I shifted back to RGB color and made tonal adjustments using the B&W as a basis.